# Can the following function be somehow exploited/used for malicious behaviour?

Tags: php

I am using a main Site Engine class which is constructing most of my pages.
I'm using this language function to change language website for all of my pages in the start of the Site Engine class:

```
`$defaultLang = 'en';

//Checking, if the $_GET["language"] has any value
//if the $_GET["language"] is not empty
if (!empty($_GET["language"])) { //<!-- see this line. checks 
    //Based on the lowecase $_GET['language'] value, we will decide,
    //what lanuage do we use
    switch (strtolower($_GET["language"])) {
        case "en":
            //If the string is en or EN
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
            break;
        case "tr":
            //If the string is tr or TR
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'tr';
            break;
        default:
            //IN ALL OTHER CASES your default langauge code will set
            //Invalid languages
            $_SESSION['lang'] = $defaultLang;
            break;
    }
}

//If there was no language initialized, (empty $_SESSION['lang']) then
if (empty($_SESSION["lang"])) {
    //Set default lang if there was no language
    $_SESSION["lang"] = $defaultLang;
}

        Template::SetLanguage($_SESSION['lang']);`
```

**I am asking two questions:**

1. Can somehow the `domain.com/?language=LANG_HERE` be exploited?
2. Since I store additional session variables upon successful login into the website: `$_SESSION['Account'], $_SESSION['Password'], $_SESSION['Email']`
   Is it possible the lang session variable to be exploited or manipulated? It's NOT user input since I'm setting it according to the response of `./?language=LANG_HERE` but still overall can this script above be exploited somehow?

Sorry if these questions seems stupid but I am still learning and I need to know that for sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good and there doesn't appear to be anything you need to be worried about.

A side note or two:

I would consider adding [trim()](https://www.php.net/trim) to your variable to clean any white space.

I am a little curious why you use `if(!empty){}if(empty){}` instead of an `if(!empty){}else{}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's appreciated. So, the code is good and I should add `trim()` here: `switch trim((strtolower($_GET["language"]))) {` , right? Also, I used `empty` like that because I struggled a bit with checking if it's empty or not. Still it works. Let me know for the trim please.

Comment: Please let me know.

Comment: `trim(strtolower($_GET["language"])) {}`

Comment: Is it actually required/better to include `trim()` on it and is there anything else major to be changed?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work after I added the `trim()`. It doesn't load the page at all. No error just white page only.

Comment: It's not required at all.

Comment: I understand but before I accept the answer, could you be so kind to let me know what may cause the issue to using `trim()` on it and displaying white page?

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy. It sounds like you have something wrong elsewhere, maybe a syntax error. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, no error at all. Just plain white page.